# analysing data using R, AWS lambda and python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was trying to replicate this post created by Amazon web services in to using R and AWS lambda [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/). Its corresponding GitHub link is at [link](https://github.com/station-x/lambda-r-survival-stats). Whilst running the following commands

```
cp /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 $HOME/lambda/lib/
cp /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 $HOME/lambda/lib/
```

I got the following errors correspondingly.

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib64/libblas.so.3': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3': No such file or directory
```

However, I managed to circumvent it by specifically installing the blas and lapack libraries

```
sudo yum -y install blas
sudo yum -y install lapack
```

However, on running the AWS lambda function - I'm getting the following module initialisation error

> module initialization error: lib/libRrefblas.so: undefined symbol:
> xerbla_

Can someone help with this? Thanks. There's also an issue raised in the last two days with respect to this.

**Update**: Found this blog that explains the process of running R on AWS lambda [link](https://jaehyeon-kim.github.io/2017/04/Serverless-Data-Product-POC-Backend-Part-I.html). It is up-to-date. As the author notes - it's befuddling that manual loading of the libraries cause the xerbla_ error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this error by forcing the use of the system version by removing the local version of the file as such:

`rm lib/libRrefblas.so`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't just remove libRrefblas.so because my version of R was looking for it (even though I had made sure to install Lapack and BLAS before installing R).  I had to

```
    rm lib/libRrefblas.so
    cp /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 lib/
    mv lib/libblas.so.3 lib/libRrefblas.so
```